# videojs apply filter (transform) to a video frame-by-frame

Tags: video.js

Is it possible to apply filters/transforms on a videojs video, frame-by-frame?

Basically, I want to get the frame (as a 2d array of pixels), do some transformations, and then pass it back to videojs for playing.

Basically, it would be similar to running ffmpeg video filters in javascript, in videojs.

Some examples:

- flip, rotate the frame
- modify the colors, change color to grayscale etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS on the video element, e.g.

```css
.vjs-tech {
  transform: scaleX(-1);
  filter: invert(1);
}
```